# How to disable button without changing of ng-if condition for input type checkbox using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, checkbox

I have one interesting situation, I have the below code.

**Js:**

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);    
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.a=10;
    });
</script>
```

**html:**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Click Me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-if="a===10"/> <br />
    <button ng-disabled="checked">Test</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I run the above code, `Test` button is not disabling. I am not sure why ?

But, as per my requirement, that `ng-if` condition should be there in `<input />` tag only and I cannot write or combine `<input />` and `<button>` tags in one `<div>` as well.

So, please help me, to have any other way to get my `Test button` should be in disabled mode on clicking of `input` type checkbox without changing of above sample code.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kiran89/pen/eYNQOpj).

Comment: when do you want to disable it  ?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni, Thanks for your response, I want to disable on clicking of checkbox, but that ng-if condition should be in <input /> tag only and I cannot write <input /> and button in one <div> as per my post.

Comment: but what do you want to do in your if condition ? If a != 10, do you want to hide the input checkbox ?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni, yes, if a !=10 means, I want to hide the input checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ng-if` create a child scope so to make `ng-model` work with `ng-if`, you need to bind it with property of an object. Something like this:

**JS**

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);    
  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.a=10;
    $scope.checkbox = {};
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Click Me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.checked" ng-if="a===10"/> <br />
    <button ng-disabled="checkbox.checked">Test</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc/pen/PoqXovy?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below :

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div>
    Click Me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked" ng-if="a===10"/> <br />
  </div> 
    <button ng-disabled="data.checked">Test</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in your script add this :

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);    
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.a=10;
      $scope.data = {};
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, it is fine and working. Thanks a lot for your time and help.